# How to change text in a Toast Notification dynamically while it's being displayed?

Tags: android, toast

I seek to create a toast whose value should reflect a number and should dynamically change while the toast is still displayed. I don't want to create new toasts for every change in the value. The changes to the value should reflect in the existing displayed toast itself. Is this possible, if so, how should I go about it?

Comment: Have you tried by using some variable or anything?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView

Comment: @MehulJoisar, I tried that but once a toast is shown, the text in it is not updated there even when the variable's value gets changed.

Comment: @DebojeetChatterjee : Ok. It seems that you have to create some custom layout or custom toast itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can save your instance of Toast which you get from [makeText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) and update it with [setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setText%28int%29).

**UPDATED**

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toast mToast;

    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.toast).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                if (mToast == null) {
                    mToast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Count " + 0, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
                mToast.setText("Count " + count++);
                mToast.show();
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Comment: Seems it's not working. The Toast is redrawn each time I use setText. Can you suggest any other way?

Comment: But what's not working? To display new text in Toast it should redraw.

Comment: By redrawn, I mean the existing toast exits and a new one pops in. I want the already existing toast that I see on screen to be updated.

Comment: Then you did something wrong, I provided sample code that works and existing toast is updated.

Comment: Apparently the problem was that I was using XUIMod on my phone to tweak toast entry and exit animations. So it would redraw the toast with the exit and entry animation each time show() was called. Disabling the tweaks fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These other answers weren't working for me. Maybe its Oreo.
This is what people are looking for. Should work in all cases.

**EDIT:** It should be clarified that original toast will only show as long as the duration allows it. Once the toast length is finished, you cannot call show() on it without re-instantiation.

```
    private Toast mToast;
    protected void showToast(int value) {

        if (mToast == null) {
            mToast = Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } else {
            mToast.cancel();
            mToast = Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

        mToast.setText("Shutdown in "+value+" seconds");
        mToast.show();
    }
```