# Android toasts showing time

Tags: android

In my application for Android the user has to tap a button and every time the button is tapped a toast appears saying "you have tapped *n* times", but if the user taps quickly several times the toasts are too slow and they appear one by one.

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    n++;
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have tapped "+n+" times", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Is there a way to "delete" all the old toasts in order to let appear only the last one?

Comment: Keep a reference to your Toast object and call .cancel() to it. [Toast.cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#cancel())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making a new Toast everytime, keep your instance and update the text

```
mToast.setText("newMessage");
```

Full example:
[How to change text in a Toast Notification dynamically while it's being displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098175/how-to-change-text-in-a-toast-notification-dynamically-while-its-being-displaye)

Comment: Didn't know you could do that. And I thought I had the 'Toast topic' pretty much exhausted.

Comment: Glad even you learned something today ;)

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to the toast and dismiss it.

```
Toast toast; 

public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (toast != null) toast.dismiss()
    n++;
    toast =  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have tapped "+n+" times", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show()
}
```