# Detect centered item in recyclerView using Carousel Layout Manager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, carousel

I am using RecyclerView with  [CarouselLayoutManager library](https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager) and i want to detect the most elevated item.
I have the method below to know if the user scrolled the recyclerview and change the current most elevated recyclerview item.

```
   recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        int overallXScroll = 0;
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            overallXScroll = overallXScroll + dx;
            //if the scroll amount will change the recyclerView item order :
            if(overallXScroll > 100){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "123", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                overallXScroll = 0;
            }
            Log.i("check","overallXScroll->" + overallXScroll);
        }
    });
```

This method works very slow and with a delay , what can i do ?

Comment: Are the logs slow too? Or is it just the Toast?

Comment: I am getting the long on time but the toast is coming with a delay @SafalSharma

Comment: Have you checked logs? Are they slow too?

Comment: Toasts are not mean't to display very fast messages like you are implementing. They are only used to display one message for certain time(like you specified as Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).
They will be displayed for that time before showing another one. Thus they are delayed.

Comment: Possibly useful, if queued `Toast`s are the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27098246/2911458

Comment: Actually, the Toast is just a test, what a really want to do is swap fragments when the most elevated item is changed, I will try to do it now that I know that what made the delay was the Toast cast time.